# Display Dropdown in HTML with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am android developer and making one admin panel for one of my android application. I know very basic PHP. currently I am displaying input field with value and user can change with text input and can save value with submit button. Its like below

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Admob On/off :-</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="text" name="ads_status" id="ads_status" value="<?php echo $settings_row['ads_status'];?>" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of input value I want show dropdown menu with two item called **on and off**. When user load page it should show value based on previous save. Like if user have made setting on it must display **on**. I am displaying value now from database. Let me know if anyone can suggest me what Should I do for it. Thanks

Comment: Why not a checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Admob On/off :-</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">   
   <select class="form-control " type="text" name="ads_status"  >
     <option value="on" <?php if($settings_row['ads_status']== 'on') echo "selected = 'selected'" ?> >On</option>
     <option value="off" <?php if($settings_row['ads_status'] == 'off') echo "selected = 'selected'" ?> >Off</option>
   </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will hep you.